# How can I capture checkboxes that I'm creating programmatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, sharepoint, innerhtml

In my code below, I'm pulling in data from SharePoint (basically an excel spreadsheet) and displaying on my page. Checkboxes are pushed to my page using .innerHTML and are given an ID programmatically.

My question: How can I determine whether those checkboxes are checked (being that they could be different each time my app loads) ?

(Once I know what is checked, I'll display more metadata on the next page based on the checks - that part I have figured out)

```
$.ajax({
url: "myWebsite",
type: "GET",
headers: { "ACCEPT": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
success: function(data){
    $.each(data.d.results, function(index) { 
    var $this = $(this);
    var courseName = $this.attr('Title'); 
    var courseNumber = $this.attr('Course_x0020_Number'); 
    var courseUrl = $this.attr('URL'); 
    var trainingGroup = $this.attr('Training_x0020_Group'); 
    var recurrence = $this.attr('Recurrence'); 

        if (trainingGroup == 'Group1') {
            if (recurrence == "Don't Specify") {recurrence = '';
            } else recurrence = " ("+recurrence+")"; 
            document.getElementById('officeListSpan').innerHTML += '<ul class="courseLists"><li><input type="checkbox" id="'+courseName.replace(/\s+/g, '')+'"/>'+courseName+recurrence+'</li></ul>';
        }
        if (trainingGroup == 'Group2') {
            if (recurrence == "Don't Specify") {recurrence = '';
            } else recurrence = " ("+recurrence+")"; 
            document.getElementById('labListSpan').innerHTML += '<ul class="courseLists"><li><input type="checkbox" id="'+courseName.replace(/\s+/g, '')+'"/>'+courseName+recurrence+'</li></ul>';
        }
    });
    },
    error:  function(){
    alert("Failed to query SharePoint list data. Please refresh (F5).");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need a way to know how many checkboxes has been created. When creating the checkboxes, them id must have a generic name and a number, for example `id="checkbox0"`, `id="checkbox1` and so on, then write the ammount of checkboxes in some part of the html code and put it some `hidden` tag. Then when reading the checkboxes data read the ammount of checkboxes and do a `for`

`function getCheckboxes(){
    var ammount = parseInt(document.getElementById("checkBoxesAmmount"));
    var checkbox;
    for(var i = 0; i<ammount; i++){
        checkbox = document.getElementById("checkbox"+i);
        //do staff
    }
    return;`

I hope this works for you c:

Comment: My only issue is the number of checkboxes could grow to infinity (at least the app needs to expect that potential) But i'll be working with this suggestion! Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

This bit of jQuery returns all the checked input boxes that are in a `ul` with the class `courseList`:

```
jQuery('ul.courseList input:checked')
```

If your question is asked because the course name might change (your checkbox IDs are based on the course name), I suggest switching to the course number instead (or an appropriate mix of the two).

If you want to know if your dynamically created checkboxes were checked and want to do this via Javascript before the form is submitted, then add a class to your checkboxes (say `dynamicCourse`) and look for get the checked checkboxes via `jQuery('input.dynamicCourse:checked')`.

Also, your checkboxes in your example don't have a `value` attribute set. If you're submitting it to a backend, you'll probably want it to have some value (course number would be my suggestion from the looks of it).